# How to place a box within a box using tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, box

I would like to draw a diagram as below. So far, i wrote this. Can you please help me in modifying this code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (8,4);
\draw (2,1) rectangle (6,3);
\node[] at (-2,2) {$\dot{x}_i(t_0)$};
\node[] at (-1,1.5) { Input};
\draw[->] (-1.5,2) -- (0,2);
\node[]  at (0.6,3.8) {$\theta_1=0$};
\draw[->] (1,2) -- (2,2);
\node[]  at (2, 3.4) {$\theta_{i+1}(t_0)=x_i(t_0)+\theta_1(t_0)$};
\node[] at (0.5,2) {$\theta_i(t_0)$};
\draw[->] (6,2) -- (7,2);
\node[] at (7.5,2) {$\dot{\theta_i}(t_0)$};
\draw[->] (6,2) -- (7,2);
\draw[->] (8,2) -- (10,2);
\node[] at (10.5,2) {$\dot{x_i}(t_0)$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome. // Please add a screenshot to your question. Perhaps then it’s easier to see, what kind of problem you encounter. Thanks

Comment: I am unsure what you want to achieve. Could you show what you intend the code to look like?

Comment: Image look like a circuit diagram, you can try with `circuitikz` instead of `tikz`

Comment: Thank you. Let me guess: 1) Do you want the theta-formulas inside the inner box to indicate its function? 2) Do you want some more space inside the outer box near input and output? 3) Anything else? // Would be good, if you'd add these clarifications to your question. Thanks

Comment: Welcome! It's not clear what your problem is; please edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about the desired result or answer but I think that using `nodes` even for the `rectangles` and forgetting fixed coordinates simplifies the drawing task.

A possible alternative:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[minimum width=4cm, minimum height=2cm, draw] (inner) {};
\draw[->] (inner.east)--++(0:1cm) node[right](thetadot){$\dot{\theta_i}(t_0)$};
\draw[<-] (inner.west)--++(180:1cm) node[left](theta){$\theta_i(t_0)$};
\node[fit=(theta) (thetadot), minimum height=4cm, draw] (outer) {};
\draw[->] (outer.east)--++(0:1cm) node[right] (x-in){$\dot{x_i}(t_0)$};
\draw[<-] (outer.west)-- node[below]{Input} ++(180:1cm) node[left] (x-out){$\dot{x_i}(t_0)$};
\node[below right=1pt and 1pt of outer.north west, align=left]{$\theta_1=0$\\$\theta_{i+1}(t_o)=x_i(t_0)+\theta_1(t_0)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]